# Aligning multiline equations

Tags: equations, align, multline

When using the multiline environment with the following code

```
    1. \(E(Y ) = aE(X) + b\). (5 marks)\par
\begin{multiline}
\begin{equation}
\E(aX+b)&=& \sum_{x}{ax+b)p(x)\\
\sum_{X}(ax\cdot p(x)+b\cdot p(x))\\
\sum_{X}ax\cdot p(x) + \sum_{X}b\cdot p(x)\\
a\underbrace{\left(\sum_{X}X\cdot p(x)\right)}_{E(X)} + b\underbrace{\left(\sum_{X}p(x)\right)}_{1}\\
a\cdot \E(X) + b}
\end{equation}
\end{multiline}
```

The equation goes over the width of the pagw, as seen in the screenshot below

[image]

I have tried to use the align environment, but it gives me an error saying that the environment cannot be recognised.

Can you help me to resolve this?

The log output file can be seen below
[image]

Comment: you surely get an error placing an `equation` inside `multiline?` do not use `equation` (or `\par`) and use `\\ ` where you want the liebreaksto occur

Comment: please don't paraphrase error messages, that makes it impossible to debug.  show a small but complete test document (from `\documentclass`  to `\end{document}` and show the exact error message from the log file.

Comment: I have used \\ where I want the line breaks.

Comment: `equation` is always one line

Comment: I have added the error from the log file.

Comment: yes multiline is a typo for multline as I wrote in my answer, it is not expected to be dfined. (it is better to show errors as text not as screenshots of an editor summary)

Answer (score 4):

As stated in @DaviCarlisle comment below his answer, your equation has sense, if You insert equal signs at begin of each equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\E{\mathrm{E}}

\begin{document}

    1. \(\E(Y ) = a\E(X) + b\).   (5 marks)
\begin{align*}
\E(aX+b) & = \sum_{x}(ax+b)p(x)\\
         & = \sum_{X}\bigl(ax\cdot p(x)+b\cdot p(x)\bigr) 
                =  \sum_{X}ax\cdot p(x) + \sum_{X}b\cdot p(x)   \\
         & = a\underbrace{\biggl(\sum_{X}X\cdot p(x)\biggr)}_{E(X)} +
            b\underbrace{\biggl(\sum_{X}p(x)\biggr)}_{1} \\
         & = a\cdot \E(X) + b
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    1. \(E(Y ) = aE(X) + b\). (5 marks)\par
\begin{multiline}
\begin{equation}
\E(aX+b)&=& \sum_{x}{ax+b)p(x)\\
\sum_{X}(ax\cdot p(x)+b\cdot p(x))\\
\sum_{X}ax\cdot p(x) + \sum_{X}b\cdot p(x)\\
a\underbrace{\left(\sum_{X}X\cdot p(x)\right)}_{E(X)} + b\underbrace{\left(\sum_{X}p(x)\right)}_{1}\\
a\cdot \E(X) + b}
\end{equation}
\end{multiline}
\end{document}
```

Produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment multiline undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8 \begin{multiline}
                     
?
```

After *any* error the pdf output is not intended to be usable.

The environment here is `multline` (no i) and should not have `equation`

But `multline` does not have `&` alignment so here it seems you want `align*`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\E{\mathrm{E}}
\begin{document}

    1. \(E(Y ) = aE(X) + b\). (5 marks)
\begin{align*}
\E(aX+b) =& \sum_{x}(ax+b)p(x)\\
&\quad\sum_{X}(ax\cdot p(x)+b\cdot p(x))\\
&\quad\sum_{X}ax\cdot p(x) + \sum_{X}b\cdot p(x)\\
&\quad a\underbrace{\left(\sum_{X}X\cdot p(x)\right)}_{E(X)} + b\underbrace{\left(\sum_{X}p(x)\right)}_{1}\\
&\quad a\cdot \E(X) + b
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used the form you had, but If I read your example correctly I would have used = on each line (not `\quad`  as I used here)

Comment: What does \quad do?

Comment: @RasaiStewart yes I added that to try to make sense of the linebreaks but on looking at the image I think these lines are all equal to the line above so should start `&=` ?

Comment: @RasaiStewart `\quad` adds 1em horizontal space